# Getting Nativescript Telerik UI RadListView to work in Angular

Tags: listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

TNS v2.5.0

I've imported `LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES` into my app.module and my template looks like

```
<ActionBar title="Events"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <RadListView [items]="events">
        <template tkListItemTemplate let-event="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Image [src]="'https:' + event.image" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/event', event.id]" [text]="event.title"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </RadListView>
</StackLayout>
```

but this displays nothing but changing to a regular `ListView` works fine.

Also If I try a `GridLayout` like

```
<ActionBar title="Events"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <RadListView [items]="events">
        <template tkListItemTemplate let-event="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <Image [src]="'https:' + event.image" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
            <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/event', event.id]" [text]="event.title"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

the app crashes with an error of

> file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/listview.js:1034:104:
>   JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'itemViewDimensions.measuredWidth') Feb  5 11:40:53 Marcuss-iMac
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.1A8C1E25-DAC0-4BA0-822E-5A6F731F1CD7.launchd_sim[31919]
>   (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.t4g[0x7b2a][36194]): Service exited
>   due to Segmentation fault: 11

Not sure if I've missed importing something somewhere but the documentation it's pretty sketchy so hard to be sure and looking at the examples

Comment: try <GridLayout rows='*'>

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Comment: Interesting this example (https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/listview/getting-started/listview-getting-started.component.html) from the official nativescript-ui repository is working fine and has the same UI structure. Can you try it out.

Comment: Tried that and still gives me the error

file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/listview.js:1034:104: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'itemViewDimensions.measuredWidth')

Comment: Tested this with the latest 2.5.0 version of NativeScript in the mentioned (https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular) repo and no error was thrown.

Comment: Note that the RadListView cannot be placed in contains of the StackLayout type, since they are measured in a way that is not compatible with that control.

Comment: This works
`<ActionBar title="Events"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout>
    <ListView [items]="events | async">
        <template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Image [src]="'https:' + item.image" height="200"></Image>
                <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item.title"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
`

Comment: This doesn't
`<ActionBar title="Events"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <RadListView [items]="events | async">
        <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Image [src]="'https:' + item.image" height="200"></Image>
                <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item.title"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
`

Comment: I get an error of `file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/listview.js:1034:104: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'itemViewDimensions.measuredWidth')`

Answer (score 5):

*LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES is for Nativescript with Javascript.*

For Angular2:

Install the plugin **tns plugin add nativescript-telerik-ui**
after this **rebuild** with tns run android in order to get a new plugin working.

in the **module.ts** add:

**import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/angular";**

and in the same file:

in the @NgModule **imports** add: **NativeScriptUIListViewModule,**

and it will be ready.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it to work.

1. Create a shared directives module, and only define the RadListView directive there.

*app/shared/shared-directives.module.ts*

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";   
import {LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES} from "nativescript-telerik-ui/listview/angular";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES
],
exports: [
    LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES
]
})
export class SharedDirectivesModule {}
```

2. Import this shared directive module in any feature/sub modules you have that use RadListView.

Here's an example.

*app/events/events.module.ts*

```
import {SharedDirectivesModule} from "../shared/shared-directives.module";
...

@NgModule({
imports: [
    ...
    SharedDirectivesModule,
    ...
],
...
})
export class EventsModule {}
```

*app/events/events.component.html*

```
<GridLayout>
  <RadListView [items]="events">
    <template tkListItemTemplate let-event="item">
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Image [src]="'https:' + event.image" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
        <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/event', event.id]" [text]="event.title"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
  </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the height of the list, by default the height will be 0px;

```html
<RadListView [items]="dataItems" height="300">
```

Comment: u saved my other half of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's required, but I have the `RadListView` in a project and also have `ListViewLinearLayout` as one of its childs:

```
<RadListView [items]="listViewItems">
  <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical"></ListViewLinearLayout>
  <template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
    <YourStuff></YourStuff>
  </template>
</RadListView>
```

And did you also add `LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES` to the list of `declarations` in your app module?

Comment: Yes LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES has been added. I'm wondering if it's some sort of issue with the latest version of nativescript as it's only just come out, and seems a bit wierd that it throws an error when inside a GridLayout. I've tried the sidedrawer and that works, unfortunately your suggestion didn't change anything.

Comment: Pity. I only tried with NativeScript 2.4, not with 2.5 so it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.
I had the LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES imported and declared in the app module. The component containing the ListView was declared in a sub-module. When I moved the decalaration of the LISTVIEW_DIRECTIVES to the sub module, the error went away.